# Next.js error in production mode - Digest: 1782794309

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I use Next 13.4.3. I don't have an API folder in the app folder as described here, by default all pgaes.tsx etc. are in the app folder SSR: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers. In my main page /app/page.tsx I do a fetch when called to load data from MongoDB (app/products/route.ts). Everything works locally as soon as I switch to production mode, I get the error below

[image]

> Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
> Digest: 1782794309

And in the Chrome Debuger Console:

> 139-fafe6b4f143efdb1.js:1 Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.

if i click on 139-fafe6b4f143efdb1.js i got this:

[image]

How do I find out where the error is?

Comment: Following the advice on the screen, what does the console say?

Comment: Try replicating the error in a development environment for more details, when you have done that; Update your post with the console output.

Comment: @Captai-N I am the same. did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue and the problem was my use of [`generateStaticParams`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params). Locally all of my code worked, it built locally and on Vercel but when I visited some routes on Vercel, this error presented itself:

> [Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.] { digest: 'DYNAMIC_SERVER_USAGE', page: '/xyz' }

This is a **key** piece of information just sort of casually mentioned in the 'Good to Know' part of the docs:

> During next build, `generateStaticParams` runs before the corresponding Layouts or Pages are generated.

You have to double check how you are rendering things in your application. We're using a mix of static and SSR which is why I got mixed up.

What happened was I used `generateStaticParams` on a path that was SSR, so the build worked because it could access the data but then the pages never got created because it's SSR. So when the client goes to the path, there's no static page to render - so you get the 500 error.

Easy fix - just get rid of `generateStaticParams` on any SSR route and you should be good.

- Next `v14.1.0` and Node `v18.x`

Edit: read Ben S' comment below. It is the use of the certain client-side functions that actually caused the 500 error. In my case it was `searchParams`.

Comment: Thanks @serraosays ! I was using `generateStaticParams` on an SSR route which doesn't make sense. After removing `generateStaticParams` the error disappeared.

Comment: I've upvoted your response, but the reasons are not quite accurate.

This error occurs due to the use of [dynamic functions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#dynamic-functions) inside the page. Such as `cookies` or use of `urlParams`.

The build will succeed, as you stated. This means, your pages are built anticipating [static rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#static-rendering-default) but at runtime, they are **using dynamic** things on the **server** => `DYNAMIC_SERVER_USAGE`

Comment: Interesting @BenS - I was using `searchParams` on that route which has to be looking at something rendered. But what do you mean 'anticipating static rendering'? I thought Next figured out the correct type of strategy when you opt into app router, no?

Comment: By 'anticipating static rendering' I mean: because of using `generateStaticParams` NextJS expects the relevant paths are statically generated, and upon visit it realizes that there are dynamic functions in use, but this does not get flagged by the build tool as the `paths` are generated before the pages are built.

Hella confusing as everything is in 1 file.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It felt like something the build should catch.

Comment: Yeah, totally confusing. Start adding in `interleaving` and you've got a recipe for a headache  tho this thread does shed some light on a few things. https://twitter.com/delba_oliveira/status/1767958810356756798

Comment: If deep prop drilling is the preferred pattern, it really takes the shine off server components.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the most optimal solution, but in my case, I found that the problem was trying to directly fetch in a server component. In my case, I converted my component to a client component using 'use client' but I changed the way of doing the fetch as follows:

create a function outside in a services file looks like this:

```
import axios from "axios";
const API_URL = '/api/item/';

const handleViewDetails = async (itemId: string) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}${itemId}`);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error:any) {
  
      const errorMessage = error.response?.data?.message || "Could not fetch item.";
      console.error('Error fetching item:', errorMessage);
      throw new Error(errorMessage);
    }
  };

  export default handleViewDetails;
```

my component looks like:

```
  "use client"
  import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
  import handleViewDetails from "./services";
  import { useParams } from "next/navigation";

  const DetailPage: React.FC = () => {
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);


  const [itemData, setItemData] = useState<ItemType | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    handleViewDetails(id)
      .then((data: item) => { 
        setItemData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error: Error) => {
        console.error("Failed to load item:", error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [id]); 

  if (loading) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }

  if (!item) {
    return <h1>No tourist data found.</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{itemData.data}</h1>
      <h1>{itemData.data}</h1>
      <h1>{itemData.data}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default DetailPage;
```

In my case, the error occurred when fetching the details of an item, which is why I'm providing this example