Is there a way to prevent React from obscuring error messages in production?
I'm working on a Next.js@14.2.5 connected to Rollbar for error logging. We are getting "An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error." from time to time and even though we can look at the logs, it would be nice to see the stack trace directly in Rollbar.
Is there a way to prevent React from obscuring the error messages?
I tried creating a ServerError class and replacing every throw new Error instance in our code, but that won't work for any unhandled exceptions or exceptions thrown in third party packages.
Edit: What I need is to prevent React from obscuring error messages, not a way to handle errors in server components.

There are a few answers on this question that should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76305664/next-js-error-in-production-mode-digest-1782794309?rq=2

This question is similar to: Next.js error in production mode - Digest: 1782794309. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
